# Ajax returns error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" when response does not arrive within 1 min

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, request, response

I am facing very strange issue.I have written django project in which I am sending ajax request.If response comes before 1 min then ajax is working fine but if response does not come within 1 min then ajax returns error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

My ajax code is as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/index/',
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 60000000,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(finalJson),
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response){
           // Get response from django server
          // do your code here
        off();
        console.log("Got response");
        console.log(response);
        if(response.includes("documents will be deleted"))
        {
                console.log("response!!!");
                if (confirm(response + '.Continue' + '?'))
                {
                        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
                        console.log("yes");
                        $.ajax({
                                url: '/index/',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({"logpaths":jsonobj,"emails":mailobj,"cu_hostname":cu_host,"user_tag":us_tag,"delete_s_date":delete_s_date,"delete_e_date":delete_e_date,"delete_docs":true}),
                                dataType: 'text',
                                success: function(response)
                                {
                                        off();
                                        alert(response);
                                }
                                });
                }
        }
       else
        {
                alert(response);
        }
        //document.getElementById("response_div").innerHTML = response;
        }
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: `timeout` only sets the client sides timeout period not  the servers, make sure your server side script is not timing out before it is done

Comment: server script is not timing out..It prints log even after client timeouts...